# Loading an image to an ink canvas, editing the image with drawing and then saving the image maintianing the size and resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

Currently I have a simple application where one button loads an image into an ink canvas as its background; as shown here:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            
    Nullable<bool> result = openFileDlg.ShowDialog();
    
    if (result == true)
    {
        global.canvas1filepath = openFileDlg.FileName;
        System.Windows.Controls.Image myImage = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                    
    
        ImageBrush canvas1Background = new ImageBrush();
        canvas1Background.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(global.canvas1filepath, UriKind.Relative));
        inkCanvas1.Background = canvas1Background;
    }
}
```

From here I can draw on the image loaded and then when I press the second button the image will save, this second subroutine is shown below:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(global.saveLocation, FileMode.Create);

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inkCanvas1.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas1.ActualHeight, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(inkCanvas1);
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
    encoder.Save(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

My issue lies in that the image I load in has dimensions of 6000x4000 and when I save the result this is reduced to 350x250. Is there a method of maintaining the size of the image throughout the process?

Comment: Sure, use an appropiate DPI value, i.e. 96 / 350 * 6000. And of course adjust the RTBs width and height accordingly. E.g. as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56331506/1136211